# How do I add content to my Wordpress news/posts page without adding content to the top of every individual post?

Tags: wordpress

I am running the latest version of WordPress along side a classic/legacy custom theme.

My issue is I am trying to add a header above posts on the news page, but this header gets applied to EVERY post.

Is there any way to add this content to just the news page and not individual posts?

I would like the news page elements to show up on only the news page, and to be able to separately style the template for posts.

Comment: is `news` is a post category page?

Answer (score 0):

use the function `is_page()` define which page you want to target ([Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/))

for example if your page slug is 'news'

```
if( is_page('news'){
    //your code
}
```